# Container is not responding to "justify-content: space-around" (css, flexbox)

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make cards on my website, cards of two (just so you know).

I have a `div` with `class="cards"` which I

```css
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cards p {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: #64958f;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #eee;
    border
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
    </p>

    <p>
    Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
</div>
```

have set its display to flex. I want its elements to have space between them (like padding on each card so that they separate out).
So, in order to do that, we have `justify-content: space-around` in flex-box but that is not working for some reason.

That's the problem I am facing.

Here's what I am getting: [image]

NOTE: I have hidden the content.
I basically want to have space between these two cards.

My desired result:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the image of the result you want?

Comment: Okay, done.....

Comment: You just have to set the width for the p elements

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `justify-content: space-around;` or `justify-content: space-between;` you need to specify the width of your elements (here `<p>`), for browser to use the remaining space as margin.

You can also set manually the `margin` (without needing to specify `width` nor `justify-content`)

```css
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cards p {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: #64958f;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #eee;
    width: 45%; /* or set margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
    </p>

    <p>
    Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide those tow content into two cards and add another mother class. in that mother class, you can add `display: flex` so that those two cards remain in the same line.

```css
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cards p {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: #64958f;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #eee;
    border-radius: 10px
}
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="cards">
      <p>
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
      </p>
  </div>
    <div class="cards"> 
    <p>
      Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set the basic width of the `p` tag.

```
.cards p {
   ...
   flex-basis: calc(50% - 80px);
}
```

Second, instead of using `flex` layout, you can use `grid` layout.

```
.cards {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   grid-column-gap: 30px;
}
```